# Default directory NPM writes into globally is not standard

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I think over the years of trials and errors I don't have standard setup any longer. For example, the defaut directory that NPM is supposed to write to is usually `/usr/local/`.

However, I can see where this is currently set by:

```
$ npm config get prefix
/Users/skube/.node


$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

I don't recall any particular reason why this is set this way. Should I just leave it as is?

Answer (score 0):

`npm` version 4.1.2 says it installs globally into `/usr/local` so I'd say your setup is non-standard.  This can occur if you use or have used `nvm` to move between versions of `node`.

I originally used `nvm` but was very unhappy with how wasteful it seemed by segregated modules based on the node version in use, functionally maintaining multiple requirement trees, one for each version of `node`.

Since that time, I've switched to "[n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n2)" and couldn't be happier. It installs globals correctly and does not maintain multiple requirement trees. Install it via `npm i -g n`.

There are several approaches to repairing your current configuration but to be safe, I'd change the npm config prefix to `/usr/local`, grab a list of the currently installed modules under your ~/.node directory, and then `npm i -g MODULE_NAME` for each, after which you can safely delete your `~/.node` directory.